# Installing Identity Server 4 Templates

Tags: c#, identityserver4

I am an Identity Server 4 Newbie attempting to follow the Identity Server 4 documentation.  As instructed, I execute the following command:

```
C:\Windows\System32>dotnet new -i IdentityServer4.Templates
```

I then see the following errors

```
C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\2.2.300\NuGet.targets(121,5): error : Unable to load the 

service index for source

https://pkgs.dev.azure.com/xxxxxx/_packaging/xxLibraries/nuget/v3/index.json.

[C:\Users\xxxx\.templateengine\dotnetcli\v2.2.300\scratch\restore.csproj]
```

`C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\2.2.300\NuGet.targets(121,5): error :   Response`

```
status code does not indicate success: 401 (Unauthorized).
```

`[C:\Users\xxxx\.templateengine\dotnetcli\v2.2.300\scratch\restore.csproj`]

I am running the command prompt as administrator, and I have tried it a couple times as some answers have suggested.

Here is my nuget.confi info:

```
  <packageSources>
    <add key="nuget.org" value="https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json" protocolVersion="3" />
    <add key="xxxxLibrary" value="https://pkgs.dev.azure.com/xxxx/_packaging/xxxxLibraries/nuget/v3/index.json" />
    <add key="Microsoft Visual Studio Offline Packages" value="C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\NuGetPackages\" />
  </packageSources>
```

Comment: Looks like it's trying to load from a NuGet feed you don't have access to: `https://pkgs.dev.azure.com/xxxxxx/_packaging/xxLibraries/nuget/v3/index.json` You should probably just load them from `nuget.org` right?

Comment: Running that command, where does the nuget  config get loaded from? @crgolden

Comment: Check your `%appdata%\NuGet\NuGet.config` file and make sure `<add key="nuget.org" value="https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json" protocolVersion="3" />` is there under the `<packageSources>` section

Comment: @crgolden sorry for the delay, ISP issues.  I have included the configuration info in my question

Comment: Can you try commenting or temporarily removing the second source (`xxxxLibrary`) and then re-running the `dotnet new ...` command? That second source seems to be the one giving you the 401 right?

Comment: @crgolden that did it.  add that as an answer for proper credit please.  Would like to know why but at least I am in business now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like the second package source (`xxxxLibrary`) is throwing a 401 for some reason. It might be an expired token, but you might try removing it temporarily to see if your `dotnet new ...` command succeeds (then put it back after).

Answer (score 6):

I was having a similar issue but I was able to get around it by specifying the nuget source to use by appending a nuget source parameter :

```
dotnet new -i identityserver4.templates --nuget-source https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json
```

Comment: How do we add api.nuget.org back to the list of default package sources so this isn't necessary?

Answer (score 0):

I came across your question and I had the same problem to fix this I found the comment above worked with me and I have succeeded to install the IdentityServer4.templates package through the command below as mentioned in the answer above

```html
dotnet new -i identityserver4.templates --nuget-source https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json
```